# VBA Hide User form but retain data entered into it

Tags: class, vba, user-controls, automation

I'm back again with what I hope is a fairly easy question.

I'm attempting to create a user form in VBA.  The user will enter certain bits of information into the form, and then close the form.  I'd like the user form to retain the data entered after it is closed by the user.  I'm treating it as a class module, since techinically they are, or at least that is how I understand it.  Here is the code I'm using:

In the main sub that displays the user form:

```
Sub NonACATMemo()

Dim UserInput As MemoReasons
Set UserInput = New MemoReasons
UserInput.Show
```

... And then in the user form itself to close it...

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
MemoReasons.Hide
End Sub
```

I also call this sub from a command button on the form.  The issue I'm running into is that when I use this method, I get an error "Run-time error '402':  Must close or hide topmost modal form first."  If I use unload me, when I try to get data out of the form it is cleared and I get a "server not available" error or something to that effect.

So, any ideas on hiding a user form but retaining the data inside?

Final couple of notes:  This is the only user form in the project, and here is an example of how I'm trying to get data out of it using the Public Property Get method:

```
Debug.Print UserInput.EmailFlag
Debug.Print UserInput.ContraFirm
Debug.Print UserInput.MemoReason
```

Well, I'm all ears if anyone has any suggestions.

Comment: you say only one userform but,  UserInput = 1 form and MemoReasons = 2 forms?

Comment: I've not seen this approach before. Why not just do `MemoReasons.Show` ?  Also, I think the problem is that you are trying to hide the form from its `Terminate` event.  I will post a suggestion.

Comment: @user2140261 I was under the impression that I had to dim and set an instance of the class for this, but it appears I was wrong.  It looks like I could perform it in the way I was initialy charging ahead, but I'd have to declare UserInput as a global variable, and then use "UserInput.Hide" on the user form to get the functionality I was looking for.  As it is, removing the declaration and set, I can use MemoReasons.Show and MemoReasons.EmailFlag etc. just fine.

Comment: @DavidZemens I placed it in the terminate event because I was under the impression that in doing so, the information in the form would be retained whether the user closed it using the X control in the top right, or the "Done" command button I placed on it.  I see it does not work that way and it seems I don't understand the terminate event correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've not seen this approach before. Normally, I would just instantiate the form by:

`MemoReasons.Show`

Indeed the `_Terminate()` event is wiping out the data held in the form. So the solution is to **not** call the `_Terminate()` event from the button-click.  Instead, simply hide the form, e.g.:

```
Sub ShowMemoReasons()
'In a normal code module, this calls the form
' could be run from the macros menu or attached to
' a shape/button/etc on the worksheet.

MemoReasons.Show

End Sub
```

Put these in the `MemoReasons` code module:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()  '<-- Rename to handle your button's click event

    MemoReasons.Hide  '## Hides the form but does not release it from memory

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
'Any events pertaining to the termination of the form object
' otherwise, all form control data will be wiped out when
' this object releases from memory

End Sub
```

After you do these, if you use the button to **HIDE** the form, you can call the `ShowMemoReasons()` and it should re-display the form, while preserving data that was previously entered in the form.

If you use the red "X" button or some other event triggers the `Terminate` event, you will lose the form data.  There are ways to do validation and prevent this with the `QueryClose` event if necessary.

**Update**

I don't think you need to `Dim` an instance of the user form (an exception would be if you will be potentially displaying *multiple* forms at the same time). Otherwise, declaring `UserInput` as a public variable is redundant and confusing.

Inicidentally, this is why you're getting the error: `Must close or hide topmost modal form first`.  If you must implement it this way, instead of doing `MemoReasons.hide` you should use `Me.Hide`.

As long as you are only displaying one instance of the form, you can always refer to `MemoReasons.property` because `MemoReasons` is a public object, just like `ThisWorkbook` or `ActiveWorksheet`, etc.

Instead, you should be able to refer to this object (`MemoReasons` is an object) in any subroutine, for example create another one that is not called from the previous subs.  Run the sub to show the form, enter in some data, and then hide the form. With the form hidden, then run this subroutine, and you should see the resulting data from the form.

```
Sub Test2()
    Debug.Print MemoReasons.EmailFlag
End Sub
```

Comment: Ah, I see now that what I was looking for was the queryclose event.  I think I'm going to scrap that part for now though and I'll have to be content with using "MemoReasons.Hide" in the command button click event.  This approach does work so long as you don't dim an instance of the class in your module.  I commented above as to how I could get that to work, but it feels clunky and sloppy.

Comment: @user2761919 see revision above which I think clarifies for you :)

Answer (score 6):

It's an old topic... hopefully someone will need a help on this.

You can do the following :

1-Place a Close/Cancel button (you can set Cancel property  to True)

2-Attach following code to  **Click** event

```
Private Sub btnClose_Click()
    'Do some stuff if necessary
    Me.Hide
End Sub
```

3-Attach this code to  **QueryClose** event

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
  If CloseMode = 0 Then 'vbFormControlMenu = 0 ([X] button on top right), see MSDN
     Cancel = True 'Don't fire Terminate event...
     btnClose_Click '...instead, call my close event handler
   End If
End Sub
```

You can check the result by placing a debugger breakpoint in **UserForm_Initialize** event and it should be fired only for the first time showing the UserForm and thus, granting UserForm state preservation.

Comment: thank you for this! I thought I knew how forms worked until tonight

Comment: @Eric Thank you sir !