# VBA Macro crash with no error message

Tags: vba, excel, macros, userform

I'm having an issue where my macro is crashing to excel with no error message.

The macro opens a first userform1, data is inputted into userform1 then a button is pressed. I have coded this button to run some code and also open a second userform (userform2) using the command:

```
    Private Sub button1_Click()
    'Some code
    Userform2.show
    'More code
    End Sub()
```

In this second userform some more data is added and the button2 is pressed to run some code. This code uses data from userform1 as well changing some textboxes in userform 1

```
    Private Sub button2_Click()
    'Some Code
    Unload Userform2
    End Sub
```

Button2_Click runs through no problems but as soon as userform2 is closed i get the crash to excel with no message. I think it is a syntax issue as the two userforms in question work in isolation.

Also, when I add a break point after Userform2.show in Button1_Click I get the error message: "Can't perform requested operation" but then the code stops at the break point. I then play the code and it doesn't crash in this instance.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to unload the userform? Can you just hide it instead? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897803/vba-hide-user-form-but-retain-data-entered-into-it

Comment: Try stepping through your macro (with `F8`) and see if that helps determine where the crash is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have stumbled across an answer. I had defined an userform1_activate event which I mistakenly wanted to use as an initialize event so having now changed this my problem has stopped.

I guess it was something to do with userform1 trying to run two subs at the same time, the activate event (when userform2 closes) and button1_click.