# How to "Snap" To the Top of a RefEdit Selection

Tags: excel, vba, events, userform

I am developing a userform in Excel 2016 using VBA.

I have 2 RefEdit controls on the userform. Once a user makes a selection in either one of the RefEdit controls and then enters the other RefEdit control to make the next selection, I would like the spreadsheet to "snap" to the top of the selection specified in the other RefEdit (this makes a big difference in usability when the selections are long).

Note: I prefer NOT to change the active cell in the worksheet when snapping to to the top.

Below is the operative code with some of the approaches I have tried (all but one commented out). The Application.Goto approach does appear to be exactly what I am looking for, however, is not currently working correctly.

```
Private Sub RefEdit1_Enter()
    If Len(Trim(RefEdit1.value)) = 0 And Len(Trim(RefEdit2.value)) > 0 Then
        Application.Goto Reference:=Range(RefEdit2).Offset(0, 1), Scroll:=True
        'Range(RefEdit2).Offset(0, 1).Select
        'Range(RefEdit2).Cells(1, 1).Select
        'SendKeys "{ESC}"
        'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub RefEdit2_Enter()
    If Len(Trim(RefEdit2.value)) = 0 And Len(Trim(RefEdit1.value)) > 0 Then
        Application.Goto Reference:=Range(RefEdit1).Offset(0, 1), Scroll:=True
        'Range(RefEdit1).Offset(0, 1).Select
        'Range(RefEdit1).Cells(1, 1).Select
        'SendKeys "{ESC}"
        'Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End Sub
```

This code does not create any error messages, it simply does not perform as desired. Might it be because there is no worksheet property associated with the Range(RefEdit*i*) specification? If so, what would be a good way of capturing the active worksheet that is associated with the RefEdit selection?

## ===============================================

I did try and capture the active workbook/sheet using this code, but it made the userform disappear:

```
Private Sub RefEdit1_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Set WBData = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set WSData = Application.ActiveWorksheet
End Sub

Private Sub RefEdit2_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Set WBData = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set WSData = Application.ActiveWorksheet
End Sub
```

Is the problem of the userform disappearing associated with the allowance of background activities issue?

Comment: you would need to fully qualify the range, e.g. wb/ws/cell, for it to be used.  this is similar to, in the userform, specifying "me" for controls.  side note, the userform will need to allow for background activities if you want the spreadsheet to start 'snapping' while the form is up.

Comment: Thanks for the response. A few follow-up questions: 1) See question edit above for question about fully qualifying the range. 2) How does one make a userform allow background activities?

Comment: *userform.show vbmodeless* should allow you to work on the spreadsheet

Comment: regarding the qualifications, inside of userform.show macro, save the workbook/worksheet as a public variable so you can utilize it in other modules

Comment: Hi Cyril, Let me run something by you: I have read of significant issues people have had in the past using modeless userforms. Might a viable option be to quickly hide the userform, have excel snap to the top of the selection, and then show the userform again instead of making the userform modeless?

Comment: I've not tried simply hiding the userform, though I have stored all inputs as variables and re-initialized the userform if a button is pressed on the userform, so i can do things on sheets then input the saved previous inputs back to the userform (same variables used for the calculations).  i assume that hiding maintains the data entered, so sounds like a safe enough bet.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897803/vba-hide-user-form-but-retain-data-entered-into-it has some more info (reading it now myself)

Answer (score 0):

example of qualifications, inclusing modeless call for userform:

```
public ws as worksheet

sub launch_userform()
    set ws = activesheet
    userform1.show vbmodeless
end sub
```

important to note that this is called before the userform, as there is no "active" sheet when the useform is the focus.

---

**edit1:**  Will give a stronger example...

within module named "moo":

```
Option Explicit

Public ws As Worksheet

Sub fdsa()
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Application.Run ("cat.mouse")
End Sub
```

within module "cat":

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub mouse()
    ws.Cells(1, 1).Value = 2
End Sub
```